# Really common linking words, verbs and pronouns list?

Tags: nlp, cpu-word

I require a simple word list to filter some sentences. What I need is to find only the meaningful words from a sentence. Like this:

```
In mathematics, and more specifically in graph theory, a graph is a representation of a set of objects where some pairs of objects are connected by links.
```

I want to get this:

```
[mathematics, graph, theory, representation, set, objects, pairs, connected, links]
```

I figured that a really common word list would help me eliminate what I don't need, but I can't seem to find a good one.

Any ideas where I could find such a list?

Comment: Looks like all those words are nouns. Just filtering out all articles and prepositions would probably be a useful step in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering verbs and prepositions, and stop words should give you the desired output. Here are sets of stop words: 
http://jmlr.org/papers/volume5/lewis04a/a11-smart-stop-list/english.stop
http://www.lextek.com/manuals/onix/stopwords1.html

Comment: expired answer, none of the links work.